# Building a regex from a set of logical expressions

Tags: php, regex, search

I have created a simple grammar for logical expressions, using boolean operators and strings as their operands, which I plan to pass as URL query strings. I am going to use it to match strings based on whether the operands in the `$query` string are present in another string, called `$text`.

Consider the following example (in PHP):

```
function search($text, $query) // $text, $query are strings
{
   // returns true if logical expression built from $query is true for $test string
   // otherwise returns false. $query explained:
   // (1) variables in $query are strings between brackets and operators
   // (2) operators are: &=and, |=or, !=not 
   // (3) priority of logical operations is defined by brackets: ()
   // (4) variable = true if substring exists in $text, false if not
}

// examples:
$text1 = 'str4 str3 blalbablastr2';
$text2 = 'str4whateverhere str3str5';

// str5 is present or str1 is present
$simpleQuery  = 'str5|str1';

// (str1 or str2 present), (str3 present), and (str4 present or str5 not present)
$complexQuery = '(str1|str2)&str3&(str4|!str5)';

search($text1, $simpleQuery);  // returns false as 'str5' OR 'str1' = false
search($text2, $simpleQuery);  // returns true  as 'str5' = true
search($text1, $complexQuery); // returns true  as 'str2' AND 'str3' AND ('str4' AND NOT 'str5') = true
search($text2, $complexQuery); // returns false as 'str1' OR 'str2' = false
```

I can program a search function using "traditional" approach:

- extract substrings and create related variables
- init variables (assign true/false depending on their existence in $text)
- build tree of operations (prioritize)
- apply operators to variables

However I believe that there is shorter & faster approach using regex. If you know regex well enough to give a practical help, please help. Thanks!

Comment: What is the `search()` function you're calling? `search` is not a built-in PHP function. Do you mean `preg_match`?

Comment: `(str4|!str5)` means `str4` OR NOT `str5`?  So anything NOT `str5`?

Comment: @vvanasten OP is asking how to write the `search()` function

Comment: @AbraCadaver I think OP means "string contains 'str4' or does not contain 'str5'"

Comment: That is almost regex, why not use regex?

Comment: I get the impression that the OP wants to write a query language, so that his users can enter an expression like the example he's given and his application will parse it and execute it. If so, he _might_ be able to "translate" from his syntax to a regex, but I have my doubts...

Comment: @wanasten - I mean that I need to develop such function.

Comment: @Kryten - yes, I want to write a query language. Sorry if it is not clear enough. I'm looking for that "translation" to regex.

Comment: @user2204231 why don't you rewrite the question to clarify it & remove the hold. I'd be interested to see the answer, since I'd like to implement something similar in one of my projects.

Comment: @Kryten - I've edited question but it is still on hold. Should I create a new one or wait when admins will de-block it?

Comment: Your question is still unclear even after your edit. Don't create a new one, please edit and be very explicit.

Comment: @2rs2ts - OK, done. Hope this should be clear enough. Or let me know what is still unclear.

Comment: I've written it in a way that I think will be explicit and I voted to reopen. However after doing a little research I don't think you can translate your grammar into regular expressions unless you limit the number of nested parenthetical expressions you can have. Arithmetical expressions are context-free grammars, which poses a problem for you. From the [University of Rochester](http://www.cs.rochester.edu/~nelson/courses/csc_173/grammars/cfg.html): "There are languages that can be generated by a context-free grammar that cannot be generated by any regular expression."

Comment: Maybe PCREs are capable of modeling arithmetical expressions but I wouldn't know since I don't write Perl (or PHP). So I do not think you could write a program which would translate your grammar into regular expressions for use in `preg_match()`. Maybe someone will demonstrate otherwise. Note [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2118309/691859) (in Python) that shows why this is not easy to do.

Comment: @2rs2ts - thanks! valuable comments.

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't need to write a `search` function if you just want to match strings. [preg_match](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) does what the search function in your example would do.

You can find information on how regular expressions work at http://www.regular-expressions.info/ if you don't understand them.

Comment: What if I use regex once a decade? should I learn it anyway? ) I'm here to get more practical and quick help. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @user2204231 If you literally use regular expressions once every 10 years, then no. But you will certainly find them useful and use them more frequently than that.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for a way of bypassing the "traditional" approach, but even with a regex approach, you'll still have to do most of the steps you outline:

- You will still need to extract substrings prior to building the regex
- You will still need to determine the correct order of operations

I think you'll only get an advantage from the regex approach if you don't use your grammar at all, and store your filters as regexes.

Here's an example of some regexes which would produce the same results as your filters:

```
# simpleQuery
str5|str1

# complexQuery (with lookahead)
(?=.*(str1|str2))
(?=.*str3)
((?=.*str4)|(?!.*str5))
```

When you start adding conjunctions (as in `complexQuery`), you end up having to explicitly cover the different orderings of your search terms, which I've dealt with by using [lookaheads](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

In simple language, the lookaheads in `complexQuery` really just state that there exists some position in the search string which is:

- Followed by any number of characters terminated with "str1" or "str2"
- Followed by any number of characters terminated with "str3"
- Either:

  - Followed by any number of characters terminated by "str4"
  - NOT followed by any number of characters terminated by "str5"

Without lookaheads, the first two lines of `complexQuery` would have to be written as:

```
((str1|str2).*str3)|(str3.*(str1|str2))
```

This second approach will become very unwieldy as you add more conjunctions.

As you can see, the regular expressions aren't anywhere near as pretty as your grammar, and I'm of the opinion that your original approach is probably the best.

Comment: A note on efficiency: these lookaheads involve backtracking, which will result in the search string being parsed once for each lookahead, so you could definitely write a more efficient algorithm if you wanted to. Have a look at the regex debugger at http://regex101.com to see the 93 steps it takes to match `text1` with `complexQuery`!

Comment: thank you for valuable comment! See my answer - it uses eval but works.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I've addressed my own question using eval().
Perhaps not the best solution (due to eval) but it works.

Note: To make life easier, I'm distinguishing substings in $query with surrounding quotes.

```
class QueryText
{
/**
 * Parses $query and performs search in $text
 *
 * @param  string $query   query string, PHP syntax, search strings should be in commas
 * @param  string $text    content to searhc
 * @param  array $options
 *
 * @return mixed          true on success,
 *                        false on failure,
 *                        null if parsing error
 *
 */
public function search($query, $text, $options)
{
    $defaultOptions =
    [
        'caseSensitive' => false
    ];

    $options = array_merge($defaultOptions, $options);

    $text  = ($options['caseSensitive']) ? $text : mb_strtolower($text);
    $query = ($options['caseSensitive']) ? $query : mb_strtolower($query);

    if (!self::isValid($query, $text)) return null;

    $evalStr = self::parse($query, $text);

    // prepare for execution
    $evalStr = 'return ((' . $evalStr . ') ? 1 : 0);';
    $result = eval($evalStr);

    return ($result===false) ? null : (($result===1) ? true : false);
}

private function isValid($query, $text)
{
    // 1. check general syntax: should be any strings in quotes; left symbols should be &&, ||, (, ), !, spaces
    $regex = '/("[^"\']+")|(\'[^\'"]+\')|(&&)|(\|\|)|([!()\s])/';
    $str   = preg_replace($regex, '', $query);
    if ($str!=='') return false;

    // 2. check brackets: should be even
    $regex   = '/([()])/';
    $matches = [];
    preg_match_all($regex, $query, $matches);
    if (count($matches[0])%2 !== 0) return false;

    // 3. check parsed expression
    $regex   = '/(\|&)|(&\|)|(&\))|(\(&)|(\(\|)|(\|\))|(&&&)|(\|\|\|)|(!\))|(^&)|(^\|)|(^\))|(&$)|(\|$)|(!$)|(\($)/';
    $str     = self::parse($query, $text);
    $matches = [];
    preg_match_all($regex, $str, $matches);
    foreach($matches as $match)
        if (count($match)!==0) return false;

    return true;
}

private function parse($query, $text)
{
    // inject true/false instead of strings
    $regex = '/("[^"\']+")|(\'[^\'"]+\')/';
    $evalStr = preg_replace_callback(
        $regex,
        function($matches) use($text)
        {
            if (trim($matches[0])=='') return '';
            $str = $matches[0];
            $str = trim($str);          // remove spaces
            $str = substr($str, 1);     // remove left quote
            $str = substr($str, 0, -1); // remove right quote
            if (strpos(trim($text), $str) !== false) return 'true';
            return 'false';
        },
        $query);

    // remove spaces and return result
    $regex = '/([\s]+)/';
    return preg_replace($regex, '', $evalStr);
}
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You can look here
https://www.php.net/preg_match
https://www.php.net/preg_match_all

```
if (preg_match("/php/i", "PHP is the web scripting language of choice.")) {
echo "A match was found.";
} else {
echo "A match was not found.";
}
```

Comment: Although `preg_match` could be used in a solution for OP's problem this answer is a bit vague and does not answer the difficult part of the question, how to get from the input format to a proper regular expression that can be passed to `preg_match`