# regular expression to evaluate or validate expression entered by user in C#

Tags: c#, regex, logical-operators

I want to split the conditional/relational/logical expression entered by user using Regex so that at run-time i can evaluate the expression entered by user. Below are few example expression entered by user.

```
Expression1 : (a==b && (c >= 10 || d!=0)) || ( a > b)

Expression2 : (c==d && a==b)
```

now i want to split entire expressions in string array for example take expression 2 and it would be like

```
string str1 = c==d;
string str2 = a==b;
```

Expression entered by user can have multiple conditions and hence dont know how to proceed.

Thanks

Comment: Why dont you just split your string by '&&' ? Another question would be: What do you expect getting out of the expression 1? How should the brackets be handled?

Comment: @C4ud3x - ya how should be brakets be handled and also  it is not always fix that it will && only.. next time user can enter with || or any other

Comment: Hah. Dude, you shouldnt ask ME. I ask YOU how you want it to be. We can maybe tell you how to code some stuff, but you should already know how you want it to behave. Strongly depends on your goal.

Comment: The dark (and interesting) art of parsing.

The main problem here is: Taking all "boolean operands" of the && and || operators and just storing them in an array will eliminate precedence of operators, and also the precedence provided by the brackets.

What you should rather consider is to get into writing simple parsers that evaluate the expressions properly. 
The result should be a logically consistent intermediate representation, that you can use for evaluation.

For simple cases see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2118309/3754223

More complex structures might become unsatisfying.

Comment: What would be the result for the 1st expression?

Comment: If your aiming at building and possibly evaluating an expression tree I believe in general case it cannot be done using regular expressions, which stems from formal language theory.

Comment: The biggest question is what do you expect your regex to do with the 1st expression?

Comment: @AlexJolig - i need to evalauate or parse the expression and also need to grab all parts(tokens) of the expression with Regex.

Answer (score 1):

Regular expressions are not the right tool for this job.

If you want to be able to evaluate arbitrary expressions you need to implement or use at least a simple form of a parser.

In the past I have used [NCalc](https://ncalc.codeplex.com/) for simple expression evaluation tasks. It is really easy to use, supports all the [operators](https://ncalc.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=operators) you used out of the box and you can even use [variables](https://ncalc.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=parameters).

There are other libraries available, this is just an example. You could also implement a parser yourself, but it might be more tricky than you think it is.